# Plasma effect in WinForms, how to create continous loop

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I'm trying to create some simple graphics ("plasma" effect) with C# and Winforms.
I have two classes in my code, (main)Form1 and Plasmadraw.

In Plasmadraw I have following setup:

```
class Plasmadraw
{

    int y;
    int x;
    double i;
   
    double pii = 3.1415;

    public void Draw(Graphics gfx, int addition)
    {

        
        for (int i = 0; i < 23040; i++)
        {

           
            x = x + 10;

            if (x == 1920)
            {
                x = 0;
                y = y + 10;
            }

            if (y == 1200)
            {
                y = 0;
            }

            double v = Math.Sin((x * 0.5) + i * 0.001 * addition);
            double c = v * pii;
            double d = c + (2 * pii / 3);
            double f = c + (6 * pii / 3);
            double r = 255 * Math.Abs(Math.Sin(c));
            double g = 255 * Math.Abs(Math.Sin(d));
            double b = 255 * Math.Abs(Math.Sin(f));

            int r1 = (int)r;
            int g1 = (int)g;
            int b1 = (int)b;

            Color e = Color.FromArgb(r1, g1, b1);

            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(e);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 10, 10);
            gfx.FillRectangle(brush, rect);

        }
        

    }
}
```

and then in Form1 I have Paint event:

```
 private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
 {
     Plasmadraw plasmaeffect = new Plasmadraw();

     for (int a = 0; a < 30; a++)
     {
          
         plasmaeffect.Draw(e.Graphics, a);

         Invalidate();
     }
```

Is this somehow completely wrong way to build the logic ? I've managed to create some graphics effects (moving sprites etc.) by creating a list and then running through the list with Foreach in Paint event (& Invalidate()). However, I'd like to learn some new way to do things, rather than copying the old way.

Comment: _Is this somehow completely wrong way to build the logic ?_ At least one mistake is to have a Invalidate call in the Paint event as this amounts to an endless loop

Comment: Also: You should turn on DoubleBuffered for the Form. And put the SolidBrush in `using`  clause so you don't leak it!! No idea if the result is want you want, though.. - As for new vs old ways: This is a good thing to explore, just keep in mind that the old way is often simply the right way and new ones often are wrong..

Comment: Thans TaW for the comments. My aim would be to have endless loop, ie. plasma effect running countinously. I thought Invalidate() is the only way, whether it is in Paint effect or handled by some Timer ?

Comment: If you really want an endless loop then code one, best in a Timer as there you get (some) control over the frame rate or in a regulrar code (`while(true)...`). Short-circuiting the system is not reall a good way, eben if it works..

Comment: I still cant figure out how where I should but the infinite loop which draws these 23040 rectangles again which little bit different colors (should create illusion of moving plasma)..hmm

Comment: Not coding on your environment However **Plasma effects** relay on indexed color gfx modes meaning you render the image once and then just change the palette by shifting it. What you do is re-render the stuff again and again which is hugely slower. Of coarse if you do not have access to indexed color gfx modes you can still emulate it ... If you switch to OpenGL then you can either use indexed modes directly or emulate them fast in shaders. If you can use bitmaps then setting them to use palette can do the same without OpenGL hoping GDI renders it fast

Comment: Aslo: Simply prerendering the images and switching them may be better. Also: Make sure to not overdraw the pixels, ie that the rectangles don't overlap. Also you could use a ColorMatrix to tweak the colors.. Then again, drawing rectangles is really cheap. I wonder what the calculations do, though..

Comment: The calculations are in place to generate needed effect in colors (waving "plasma" effect). I'm beginner in C#, therefore my competence is not currently enough for Opengl. I tried to implementate Timer which would Invalidate() the drawing canvas and also run method which would update the "addition" in loop. However, nothing happens ?  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            plasmaeffect.Update();
            Invalidate();} and in Plasmadraw class:  public void Update()
        {
            addition++;

        }